# Count the number of occurrences of certain values of TagName column

Tags: sql-server, count

I want to count the number of occurrences of different sensor rows in SQL, but I seem to be doing it wrong and seemingly I am not visualizing it correctly.

If I was doing this in pseudocode in a C style language, I would do it like this:

```
FOR i in range(taglist[i]):
    
    print(taglist[i], count(taglist[i]) )
```

I have been trying this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (
           SELECT DISTINCT [TagName]
           FROM   [A2ALMDB].[dbo].[AlarmMaster]
           WHERE  (TagName LIKE '%Sensor%' OR GroupName LIKE'%Sensors%')
       ) a
```

It returns 66, but I want it to return the count of each of the distinct tagnames that are returned in `SELECT ... FROM (...)a`.

Can anyone help me with how I should be trying to get all the counts of my different sensor occurrences to total instead of a count of all the distinct tagnames?

Comment: Just to clarify for any beginner who might come across this and get confused, this query as posted wouldn't work. If you run it, it will return an error: "Invalid column name 'a'". The `COUNT` function accepts either a column reference or a `*`, and the `a` in this case is a table reference, not a column. In the actual query probably either something else was there in place of `Count(a)` or the derived table's column was aliased as `a` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a simple `group by`:

```
select tagname, count(*)
from alarmmaster
where tagname like '%Sensor%'  
   or groupname like '%Sensor%'
group by tagname;
```